# How can I get login and signup with a single class based view?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Currently I have different Signup and Login Views both implemented as class based view, and are used at diffrent urls. Both use the same form which has two fields `email` and `password`. 
These two views have different `form_valid` and thus different logic. So, signup view creates a user, sends verification mail etc. Login view only logs the user in.

The use case has changed to allow both signup and login at the same url using a single form.

I want to have the same view, handle both these conditions. So, when form is submitted, I will check if a user exists in db with the submitted email. If yes then use LoginView logic. If not then use SignupView logic. How can I handle both these conditions in a single view by reusing SignupView and LoginView.

Comment: Extract the business logic out of the view into methods, and call those methods from your combined view.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use one Form and one view.
This form check if email exist, if it exist, raise a ValidationsError

```
class LoginOrSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

    def clean_email(self):
        existing = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email'], username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        if existing.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A user with this e-mail already exists."))
        return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

And then in your view

```
if form.is_valid():
    #signup
elif form['email'].errors and form['email'].errors[0] == _("A user with this e-mail already exists."):
    #login
    user = auth.authenticate(username=form['email'].value(), password=form['password'].value())
    auth.login(request, user)
```

This solution work in function based view. So for your case you want to use CBV, we can just override form_invalid methods in your CBV:

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    if form['email'].errors and form['email'].errors[0] == _("A user with this e-mail already exists."):
        user = auth.authenticate(username=form['email'].value(), password=form['password'].value())
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpRedirect('your page')
    return super(YouViewName, self).form_invalid(form)
```

For the form_valid we don't need to override it, just keep in mind that if your form is valid, it should register a new user. In this case a `django.views.generic.CreateView` can help.